# A paraboloid is a surface.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

$$z=x^2+y^2$$ gives paraboloid.

Let $\sigma$ be a surface patch for a paraboloid defined by $$\sigma (u,v)= (u,v, u^2+v^2)$$

I want to show that this is a surface.

To show that $\sigma S is 1-1 continuous with inverse continuous is enough to prove that this is a surface. Right?  Or using atlas, should I prove this question? If I need to use atlas, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, proving that $\sigma$ is continuous with continuous inverse is sufficient. Also $\{ \sigma \}$ gives an atlas consisting of only one chart.

Comment: Why ? $(1,0,2u)\times (0,1,2v) $ is not a zero vector

Comment: And it shouldn't be. In case that happens something is wrong, because the tangent vectors must always be linearly independent.